# what would happen if nodes in hadoop change their IP address?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, ip

my hadoop clusters do not work fine because of the network conditions.What if i change the entire network,like another router,thus change the IP addresses? could the clusters still work by updating some configurations? or i must torn it down and rebuilt everything?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works once you change the ip addresses into the configuration, why did not you use the DNS?

Ok, it was not a good answer, let me apologize and give a better answer.
If you need to change configuration on a running cluster you can decommission and commission the data nodes.

Switch off the data node is not a good idea.

**Data Node Decomissioning**

The fist step is tell to yarn you are going to remove some nodes, then you have to say the same to node manager.

I don't know if your system is configured for decommissioning, if it so you have the key `yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path` into the `yarn-site.xml` and `dfs.hosts.exclude` into `hdfs-site.xml`

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.hosts.exclude</name>
  <value>$YOUR_PATH/dfs.exclude</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.hosts.exclude</name>
  <value>$YOUR_PATH/dfs.exclude</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

Open the file `$YOUR_PATH/dfs.exclude` and add hostnames / ip addresses of node you need to stop.

execute

```
yarn rmadmin  -refreshNodes
hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes
```

Check if the data nodes are in decommission checking the web interface.

**Data Node Comissioning**

Works in the same way of the Decommissioning

yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.include-path</name>
  <value>$YOUR_PATH/dfs.include</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.hosts</name>
  <value>$YOUR_PATH/dfs.include</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

Open the file `$YOUR_PATH/dfs.include` and add hostnames / ip addresses of node you need to add.

```
yarn rmadmin  -refreshNodes
hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes
```

wait some time

```
 hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

Now the hosts you added are into the list.

If your configurations are missing the above keys you need to halt/restart the node manager and yarn after adding them.

Using these procedure you can halt data nodes in a safe way.

Comment: don't quite understand, would you explain in detail ? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you need to change all the ip address of the machines in your cluster, it's the only thing you have to change.  Nothing to explain.

Comment: My sincere thanks! Didn't expect such detailed answer before,it will definitely help in the soon future.